# Where should I place my .vimrc not being processed on Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, vim

I just started a new job, and I've installed vim and gvim on the machine.  I'm trying to get my `.vimrc` working, I've placed it in the directory that `%USERPROFILE%` points to, but vim isn't picking it up.

But while `%USERPROFLE%` does point to `C:\users\<me-name>` I've noticed that `My documents` are stored on an external share somewhere.

The share is also mapped...and I've tried putting .vimrc out there to, to no avail.

Is there some other place I can put .vimrc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows, the `.vimrc` file is stored as `_vimrc`

For more information Refer: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_vimrc_file

It has all the information you need and more.

Comment: Well that's weird on my other computer I called it .vimrc and it worked just fine...did they change something recently?

Comment: Wait that didn't work either...I ran the command to see where $HOME is and it says $HOME is U:\, but I don't have a U:\ .... ???

Comment: I ended up editing the main one, instead of the user one that overrides it.

Comment: I wonder why it works on my old windows system at home with .vimrc